# publist produces entry "with and <second author>" when omitting first author

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

I produce a publist with the current version of publist (File: publist.bbx 2018/09/01 v.1.11) and get in entries where I am the first author "(with and XX)", but not when I am not the first author (second or later). 
[image: the first entry is wrong, the second correct]
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=publist]{biblatex}

\plauthorname{Frank}
\begin{filecontents}{mwebib.bib}

@Article{Frank1994e,
    author  = {Frank, Andrew U. and Timpf, Sabine},
    title   = {Multiple Representations for Cartographic Objects in a Multi-Scale Tree - An Intelligent Graphical Zoom},
    journal = {Computers and Graphics Special Issue on Modelling and Visualization of Spatial Data in GIS},
    year    = {1994},
    volume  = {18},
    number  = {6},
    pages   = {823--829},
}

@Article{Buyong1991,
    author  = {Buyong, Taher and Kuhn, Werner and Frank, Andrew U.},
    title   = {A Conceptual Model of Measurement-Based Multipurpose Cadastral Systems},
    journal = {Journal of the Urban and Regional Information Systems Association (URISA)},
    year    = {1991},
    volume  = {3},
    number  = {2},
    pages   = {35--49},
}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\title{XX publications}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\maketitle


\section{Articles}
\newrefsection[mwebib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]  


\end{document}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, but I don't have time right now to look into it. Even if you get an answer here quickly, please consider reporting this at https://github.com/jspitz/biblatex-publist/issues. It looks very much like a small bug in the style and I'm sure the developer would be happy to hear about it so he can have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for checking. I have repored a bug, as you suggest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note**: The maintainer of `biblatex-publist` (@JSpitzm here at TeX.SX) reports that [the fix below has been included to the package, as of version 1.12](https://github.com/jspitz/biblatex-publist/issues/18), which should be available soon. So, as long as you can update, you should no longer need this in your preamble.

I'm not sure what might have changed or where, but if I had to guess the new name wrapper formatting directives introduced somehow a grouping for individual names thus messing with the toggles used by `biblatex-publist` in its name formatting directives.

**Update**: @moewe identified the place the grouping was introduced, and it was not in the new name wrapper formatting facilities as my uninformed hunch would have, but in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/731.

Making the toggling of `myselfprec` and `hadmyself` global in the `author` and `editor` name formatting directives seems to solve the issue. And, as far as I can tell, these toggles are only used there, so making them global should be harmless.

Unfortunately, those formatting directives are quite long, even when the changes introduced are small.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=publist]{biblatex}

\plauthorname{Frank}
\begin{filecontents}{mwebib.bib}

@Article{Frank1994e,
    author  = {Frank, Andrew U. and Timpf, Sabine},
    title   = {Multiple Representations for Cartographic Objects in a Multi-Scale Tree - An Intelligent Graphical Zoom},
    journal = {Computers and Graphics Special Issue on Modelling and Visualization of Spatial Data in GIS},
    year    = {1994},
    volume  = {18},
    number  = {6},
    pages   = {823--829},
}

@Article{Buyong1991,
    author  = {Buyong, Taher and Kuhn, Werner and Frank, Andrew U.},
    title   = {A Conceptual Model of Measurement-Based Multipurpose Cadastral Systems},
    journal = {Journal of the Urban and Regional Information Systems Association (URISA)},
    year    = {1991},
    volume  = {3},
    number  = {2},
    pages   = {35--49},
}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
 \if@hlauthor%
   % Embolden omitted author
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartfamily}{\bpl@tsurname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartgiven}{\bpl@tfirstname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartprefix}{\bpl@tvonpart}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@osurname}{\bpl@esurname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@ofirstname}{\bpl@efirstname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@ovonpart}{\bpl@evonpart}%
   \ifboolexpr{
      test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@esurname}{\bpl@tsurname} }
      and
      ( test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@efirstname}{\bpl@tfirstname} } or test { \ifdefstring{\bpl@ofirstname}{} })
      and
      ( test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@evonpart}{\bpl@tvonpart} } or test { \ifdefstring{\bpl@ovonpart}{} }) }
          {\toggletrue{ismyself}}{\togglefalse{ismyself}}%
   \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{}{%
       \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}%
          {\multinamedelim}%
          {\finalnamedelim}%
   }%
   \iftoggle{ismyself}{\plauthorhl{%
      \if@givenfirst% given name first
         \ifgiveninits
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
          \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
          \namepartfamily%
       \else% family name first
          \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
          \namepartfamily%
          \ifgiveninits
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
      \fi
   }}{%
     \if@givenfirst% given name first
         \ifgiveninits
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
          \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
          \namepartfamily%
       \else% family name first
          \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
          \namepartfamily%
          \ifgiveninits
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
      \fi
   }%
   \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
 \else% \if@hlauthor false
   \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{\ifthenelse{\value{author}>1}{\bibopenparen\bibstring{with}\addspace}{}}{}%
   % Exclude omitted author
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartfamily}{\bpl@tsurname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartgiven}{\bpl@tfirstname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartprefix}{\bpl@tvonpart}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@osurname}{\bpl@esurname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@ofirstname}{\bpl@efirstname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@ovonpart}{\bpl@evonpart}%
   \ifboolexpr{
      test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@esurname}{\bpl@tsurname} }
      and
      ( test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@efirstname}{\bpl@tfirstname} } or test { \ifdefstring{\bpl@ofirstname}{} })
      and
      ( test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@evonpart}{\bpl@tvonpart} } or test { \ifdefstring{\bpl@ovonpart}{} }) }
          {\global\toggletrue{myselfprec}\global\toggletrue{hadmyself}%  <- %  change here
           \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1\AND\value{liststop}=1}
                   {\stepcounter{liststop}}{}}
          {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{\global\togglefalse{hadmyself}}{% <- change here
          \ifboolexpr{
              test { \iftoggle{myselfprec} }
              and
              test { \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{3} } }
              {}{%
                 \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}-1}%
                    {\multinamedelim}%
                    {\iftoggle{hadmyself}{%
                        \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}%
                           {\multinamedelim}%
                           {\finalnamedelim}}
                       {\finalnamedelim}}%
                }%
          }%
          \ifgiveninits
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
          \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
          \global\togglefalse{myselfprec}% <- change here
          \namepartfamily}%
          \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
   \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\value{liststop}\AND\value{author}>1}{\unspace\bibcloseparen}{}%
 \fi% end of \if@hlauthor else condition
}

\DeclareNameFormat{editor}{%
 \if@hlauthor
   % Embolden omitted editor
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartfamily}{\bpl@tsurname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartgiven}{\bpl@tfirstname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@osurname}{\bpl@esurname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@ofirstname}{\bpl@efirstname}%
   \ifboolexpr{
      test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@esurname}{\bpl@tsurname} }
      and
      ( test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@efirstname}{\bpl@tfirstname} } or test { \ifdefstring{\bpl@ofirstname}{} })
      and
      ( test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@evonpart}{\bpl@tvonpart} } or test { \ifdefstring{\bpl@ovonpart}{} }) }
          {\toggletrue{ismyself}}{\togglefalse{ismyself}}
      \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{}{%
         \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}-1}%
            {\multinamedelim}%
            {\finalnamedelim}%
      }%
      \iftoggle{ismyself}{\plauthorhl{%
          \if@givenfirst% given name first
            \ifgiveninits
                {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
                {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
             \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
             \namepartfamily%
          \else% family name first
             \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
             \namepartfamily%
             \ifgiveninits
                {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
                {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
         \fi
       }}{%
         \if@givenfirst% given name first
            \ifgiveninits
                {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
                {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
             \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
             \namepartfamily%
          \else% family name first
             \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
             \namepartfamily%
             \ifgiveninits
                {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
                {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
         \fi
      }%
      \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
 \else% \if@hlauthor false
   \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{\ifthenelse{\value{editor}>1}{\bibopenparen\bibstring{with}\addspace}{}}{}%
   % Exclude omitted author
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartfamily}{\bpl@tsurname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\namepartgiven}{\bpl@tfirstname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@osurname}{\bpl@esurname}%
   \bpl@normalize{\bpl@ofirstname}{\bpl@efirstname}%
   \ifboolexpr{
      test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@esurname}{\bpl@tsurname} }
      and
      ( test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@efirstname}{\bpl@tfirstname} } or test { \ifdefstring{\bpl@ofirstname}{} })
      and
      ( test { \ifdefstrequal{\bpl@evonpart}{\bpl@tvonpart} } or test { \ifdefstring{\bpl@ovonpart}{} }) }
          {\global\toggletrue{myselfprec}\global\toggletrue{hadmyself}% <- change here
           \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1\AND\value{liststop}=1}
                   {\stepcounter{liststop}}{}}
          {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{\global\togglefalse{hadmyself}}{% <- change herey
            \ifboolexpr{
              test { \iftoggle{myselfprec} }
              and
              test { \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{3} } }
              {}{%
                 \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}-1}%
                     {\multinamedelim}%
                     {\iftoggle{hadmyself}{%
                         \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}%
                             {\multinamedelim}%
                             {\finalnamedelim}}
                        {\finalnamedelim}}%
                }%
          }%
          \ifgiveninits
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
             {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
          \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
          \global\togglefalse{myselfprec}% <- change here
          \namepartfamily}%
          \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
   \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\value{liststop}\AND\value{editor}>1}{\unspace\bibcloseparen}{}%
 \fi% end of \if@hlauthor else condition
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{XX publications}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Articles}
\newrefsection[mwebib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The analysis is spot on, but one small correction: The grouping that keeps the toggles here local was not introduced by the new wrappers (phew!), it was introduced explicitly in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/731 to fix a different bug in `biblatex`.

Comment: @moewe Btw, the new name/list wrappers are a very neat addition. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I fixes indeed the issue for me. Thank you very much for the quick response! - the fix is quite long and I have put it in a file to include; is there a better solution?

Comment: @user855443 There's no harm in that and, if it helps keeping your stuff organized in a way that suits you, it is fine. Anyway, until the fix arrives in the package itself, you will have to maintain this being called somehow in your preamble. Just keep an eye to remove it when the fix does come.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, all. Will be fixed in biblatex-publist 1.12 (to be released today).

Comment: @StefanPinnow We cannot delete the response of the package creator. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist?lang=en

Comment: @StefanPinnow I beg to disagree. The question points towards a bug in the biblatex-publist package, and I think it is relevant to announce here that I have fixed this bug (which makes the workaround obsolete).

Comment: I added you to the list of maintainers of the `biblatex-publish` package, I omitted the others, you can fix it if you want here https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here

Comment: For me this would also be ok, but in the past, answers related to "update the package" where removed quite often and instead it was requested to put a comment below the question (or an answer which incorporated the fix).

Comment: I will have to learn how to update my installation! Thank you for the tool!